# How to open iframe calendar in new window

Tags: javascript

I have "iframe version" of the calendar. The click able dates in the calendar link to som site. They will open in same window (top target), but I want to open in new window (blank).

How can I do this using javascript?

Comment: You are saying "the calendar", but what kind of calendar are you using? To open a link in a new window you need `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing something similar to this. It does require [jQuery](http://jquery.com) though.

```
$(function() {
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('iframe').contents().find('a[target=_top]').click(function() {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    });
})
```